# SharePoint Online SPFx Web Part Issue

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, error, spfx-webparts, modern-experience

Your web part will not appear in the toolbox. Please make sure "gulp serve" is running in a web part project. Please refresh the page once "gulp serve" is running.

[image]

Comment: Where are you seeing this message? On SharePoint workbench while debugging the solution or on SharePoint page after web part deployment?

Comment: I'm seeing this message On SharePoint workbench while debugging.

Comment: Is gulp serve running correctly? check if there are any errors in command prompt console.

Comment: *[spfx-serve] To load your scripts, use this query string: ?debug=true&noredir=true&debugManifestsFile=https://localhost:4321/temp/manifests.js* showing in the command prompt console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@ariyan,

When you run `gulp serve`, you get a lot of messages on the screen, which may be confusing. Especially when there's one that says something like  `Opening https://enter-your-SharePoint-site/_layouts/workbench.aspx using the default OS app` which -- every time -- makes me go "Oh, the web part must be ready!"... but it isn't... yet.

The trick is to wait for `Finished subtask`**`'reload'`**`after x.xx ms`. Only then will the web part be ready, and you should be able to reload the workbench page and find your web part.

If that doesn't work, you may want to make sure that you installed the self-signed developer certificate by using `gulp trust-dev-cert` and accepting the prompt (which may sometimes appear in a background window).

If you're using sample code (or code that you didn't build yourself) and you're still experiencing issues, you may want to make sure that the environment you're using is compatible with your SPFx solution by using the [Microsoft 365 SPFx Doctor](https://github.com/pnp/cli-microsoft365/blob/main/docs/docs/cmd/spfx/spfx-doctor.md) command, by running `m365 spfx doctor` from the root of the project folder after you installed the CLI for Microsoft 365.

If all else fails, please provide us more information so we can help you better.

I hope this helps?

Comment: I have tried all of these options, and it is still not working for me. I wait until the `reload` task completes, but then refresh the page and the error is still there.

`gulp trust-dev-cert` completes successfully
`m365 spfx doctor` runs. It finds yo version 3.3.1 and recommends installing version 4; however, when I run `npm list -g --depth=0`, it shows that I have version 4 installed.

Any ideas?

Comment: Update: Now I feel dumb, but I will comment in case it helps someone. I was using brave browser with "Shields Up" -- it was blocking something that was required for this to work correctly. I turned off the "Shields Up" option, and it works well.